# Local Npm module "jshint-stylish" not found. Is it installed?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, gruntjs, jshint

Hi I am building docker image from node js project.

docker files contents are like below

fetch code from git repo.
install npm
install grunt cli
grunt build

please see below docker file

```
FROM    ubuntu:latest
# Install Node.js and npm
RUN    apt-get -y update
RUN    apt-get -y install nodejs npm git wget curl
RUN     git config --global http.sslverify false
WORKDIR /somerepo/
RUN git clone -somerepo
WORKDIR /somerepo/src/
RUN     npm cache clean -f
RUN     npm install -g n
RUN     n stable
RUN     npm install
RUN     npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN     grunt build
EXPOSE  3000
CMD ["node", "web.js"]
```

but its grunt build step is failing below error in logs

Step 14/15 : **RUN     grunt build**
 ---> Running in d0f8863081f1

> > **Local Npm module "jshint-stylish" not found. Is it installed?**

Running "clean:dist" (clean) task

...
...
...

Running "githooks:all" (githooks) task

Binding `jsbeautifier:pregit` to `pre-commit` Git hook.
OK

**Running "jshint:dev" (jshint) task
Warning: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object Use --force to continue.**

Do any have any idea why grunt build is not ending successufully ?

I have already tried --save-dev option and also tried manually installing jshint with below command

```
#RUN npm install --save-dev jshint-stylish
```

**Also i tried to print the files/directories having pattern "*jshint*" with below command in dockerfile**

```
RUN find . -name "*jshint*"
```

and its printing below output in logs

```
Step 13/15 : RUN find . -name "*jshint*"
 ---> Running in db355c19f75a
./node_modules/.bin/jshint
./node_modules/ascii-table/.jshintrc
./node_modules/bl/.jshintrc
./node_modules/errno/.jshintrc
./node_modules/escodegen/.jshintrc
./node_modules/estraverse/.jshintrc
./node_modules/exit/.jshintrc
./node_modules/findup-sync/.jshintrc
./node_modules/gaze/.jshintrc
./node_modules/getobject/.jshintrc
./node_modules/globule/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-compress/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/tasks/jshint.js
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/tasks/lib/jshint.js
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-express-server/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-git-describe/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-githooks/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/.bin/jshint
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/docs/jshint-examples.md
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/docs/jshint-options.md
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/docs/jshint-overview.md
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/tasks/jshint.js
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/tasks/lib/jshint.js
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/test/jshint_test.js
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/jshint
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/jshint/packages/jshint
./node_modules/grunt-img/node_modules/jshint/packages/jshint/jshint.js
./node_modules/grunt-jsbeautifier/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-json-replace/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-legacy-log/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-legacy-log-utils/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-legacy-util/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-lib-contrib/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-manifest/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-prettify/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-sloc/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-sloccount/.jshintrc
./node_modules/grunt-text-replace/.jshintrc
./node_modules/handlebars/.jshintrc
./node_modules/ibrik/node_modules/estraverse/.jshintrc
./node_modules/isstream/.jshintrc
./node_modules/istanbul/node_modules/estraverse/.jshintrc
./node_modules/jshint
./node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint
./node_modules/jshint/src/jshint.js
./node_modules/jshint-stylish
./node_modules/keep-alive-agent/.jshintrc
./node_modules/less/.idea/jsLinters/jshint.xml
./node_modules/less/.jshintrc
./node_modules/log4js/.jshintrc
./node_modules/nodemon/.jshintrc
./node_modules/phantomjs/.jshintrc
./node_modules/promise/.jshintrc
./node_modules/prr/.jshintrc
./node_modules/request-progress/.jshintrc
./node_modules/resolve-url/.jshintrc
./node_modules/restify/node_modules/qs/.jshintignore
./node_modules/restify/node_modules/qs/.jshintrc
./node_modules/save/.jshintignore
./node_modules/save/.jshintrc
./node_modules/shelljs/jshint.json
./node_modules/source-map-resolve/.jshintrc
./node_modules/source-map-url/.jshintrc
./node_modules/undefsafe/.jshintrc
./node_modules/urix/.jshintrc
./node_modules/xtend/.jshintrc
```

**if anyone have any idea what is wrong please let me know**

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Local Npm module "jshint-stylish" not found when it exists locally (via symlink)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143154/error-local-npm-module-jshint-stylish-not-found-when-it-exists-locally-via-sy)

Comment: Already gone through that link, didn't work for me !!!!